# Singular CAS vs Macaulay2 for finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, math-software, computer-algebra-systems, macaulay2

I intend to work on error correcting codes using finite fields. Finite fields are supported by both Singular and Macaulay2. I am confused about which one I should start with to learn.

Any suggestions regarding which will be better?

Comment: @DietrichBurde:problem with using sage is that it cannot be used to contribute libraries for individual project. User always remains at receiving end while using a standalone CAS one can expect to master it in long run and contribute also.

Comment: I'd suggest to look at the GUAVA package for GAP: see http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/guava.html. Also, I can not see what do you mean in the comment regarding Sagemath and standalone CAS.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Thanks I am aware of this package though I am still to use it. I used GAP to learn group theory, its great. Regarding my comment, all I meant is that its better to work on one CAS rather than a terminal that calls other CAS because sage workbooks cannot be used as libraries in these CAS like(GAP,Maxima etc).

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, in the case one just needs GAP, I'd always suggest just to use it directly. GAP included in Sage differs, and default installation of Sage does not contain GAP packages except needed GAPDoc, and many data libraries. The other question is if you need to combine several systems or use Sage functionality as well - it's not just a terminal, but also contains a lot of own code.